# Thoughts of time tracker mockup

Tags: ux-field

I am new to web design, HTML, CSS, and Javascript. This is a first attempt to create a time tracker. Both for manual inputs and stop watch.

So far it has no connection to a database, so it is more about the user interface, look and feel.

http://94.237.92.101:5050/

(Note that this is an HTTP and some browsers must be forced not to use https.)

Am I on the right track? Else please point me in another direction.

Comment: Hi sibert, questions about site reviews are off topic here because they only help one person. Try to rephrase your question into a more general problem.

Comment: @sibert You question is too general and most probably will not receive any answer. Could you provide additional information on how your time tracker will be used by your audience, what is special in your time tracker what made you to make 'just another one', what namely is most interesting for you to know - layout, colors, actions, etc. This will make your question a real question.

Comment: Hey Sibert, please __post some screenshots__ of your web page! I can't access it and would like to give you the asked __review for the UI-design__ 

Answer (score 1):

1. While creating a form, when input is filled with the answer is good to show the description of the input field - label. For instance by using floating labels.
2. Select code field - I'm able to write anything I want in this field even though it's a dropdown menu. Moreover, I don't get any feedback if the field is filled incorrectly. When the field is not active/ focused anymore I would consider a feedback message with the information for the user that field is not filled correctly.

Comment: Thank you for your thoughts. "I don't get any feedback if the field is filled incorrectly." There is always a battle if you should alert while entering or at submit. I have put the verifying at the input.